# Как расположить блоки?

Tags: html, jquery, css

- html разметку трогать нельзя.
- использовать нужно `flex-ы`.

Первые три блока из разметки html должны быть тремя сверху, остальные три блока должны быть нижними. нужно было их расположить, так как я сделала с помощью флексовского свойства order. Но есть большое ***НО***. В условии сказано, что первые два блока не обязательны, первого может не быть, и второй не должен занимать его место, точно так же второго может не быть, но первый должен оставаться на своем месте, собственно как и третий и все остальные.

```css
.block {
  background: #fcfcfc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.block_item {
  background: red;
  margin: 5px;
}

.item1 {
  width: 129px;
  height: 70px;
  order: 1;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  align-self: auto;
}

.item2 {
  order: -1;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  align-self: auto;
  width: 30%;
}

.item3 {
  order: 0;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  align-self: auto;
  width: 30%;
}

.item4 {
  order: 3;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  align-self: auto;
  width: 50%;
}

.item5 {
  width: 85px;
  height: 50px;
  order: 2;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  align-self: auto;
}

.item6 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  order: 5;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  align-self: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="block_item item1">Должен быть третим</div>
    <div class="block_item item2">Должен быть первым</div>
    <div class="block_item item3">Должен быть вторым</div>
    <div class="block_item item4">Должен быть пятым</div>
    <div class="block_item item5">Должен быть четвертым</div>
    <div class="block_item item6">Должен быть шестым</div>
  </div>
  <p>Второй контейнер .block, дублирующий первый, только без блока .item3, все сместилось..</p>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="block_item item1">Должен быть третим</div>
    <div class="block_item item2">Должен быть первым</div>
    <div class="block_item item4">Должен быть пятым</div>
    <div class="block_item item5">Должен быть четвертым</div>
    <div class="block_item item6">Должен быть шестым</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Блок с классом `.block` по типу контейнера со статьями, и в следующих контейнерах `.block` уже изначально в разметке может не быть блока с классом `.item2` или `.item1`.

Вопрос, как это сделать? Если с разметки убираю какой-то из первых блоков, естественно остальные смещаются... И еще важно то, что на мобилках все блоки просто сужаются, но остаются все на своих местах.

Answer (score 0):

По поводу смещающихся блоков: вариант первый ненужный блок не удалять из разметки а скрывать (через opacity например), или второй вариант - добавлять margin-left:auto второму блоку если убран первый или же margin-right:auto в обратном случае.

По поводу просто сужающихся блоков для мобилки: у вас размеры заданы в процентном соотношении от ширины контейнера, соответственно они при любом разрешении браузера будут занимать заданный % от ширины.... используйте @media запросы для малых размеров браузера и в них задавайте нужные ширины